# PhoneGap (Android): Simplest and fastest way to backup localStorage to cloud?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, local-storage, phonegap

What is the best, simplest and fastest way to backup (& retrieve) a simple string to cloud in PhoneGap?
I have successfully exported the whole localStorage object as a string. Now i just want to backup this string to the cloud whenever the user opens the app and be able to retrieve it whenever required.

I tried this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cloud-settings
following all the api, i still couldn't get it to work. I dont know what exactly is the problem.

What are some other options i have to do this apart from this plugin? It should be as simple as possible.

Comment: I'm using that plugin and have got it to store and retrieve from the cloud just fine. What I can't get it to do is synch data between two different devices.

Answer (score 1):

If that `string` does not contain any private data...
I would use http server (maybe [NodeJS](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp) or [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)).
I will also use any simple database to store data.

On client side I will use [POST and GET](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to store and retrieve that `string`.
To store string I will use POST method passing user ID and String as parameters in URL.
To retrieve data I will use GET method passing user ID.
Also you can POST and GET Json as string.

If data is sensitive I would also do it in the same way. Keeping connection secure using HTTPS.
Parameters in URL are not visible when connection is secure.